# $\inf$ and $\sup$ of the following sets

Tags: real-analysis

(p12 Exercise 1.3.6 Understanding Analysis, Abbott) I try to determine the $\inf$ and $\sup$ of the following sets. Can you tell me if my result is correct? I am also interested in how to compute it. Now I only determined it by varying the values.

Define sets $B= \{ {n \over n + m } : m,n \in \mathbb N\}$, $C = \{ {n \over 2n + 1} :n \in \mathbb N\} $, $D= \{ {n \over m} : n , m \in \mathbb N , n+m \le 10 \}$. The $\inf$ and $\sup$ is:

$\inf B =0, \sup B = 1$ ,

$\inf C = 0, \sup C = {1 \over 2}$,

$\inf D = 0, \sup D = \infty$.

Comment: For instance, show 1 is *an* upper bound, then show it is the *least* such.

Comment: $\inf C \ne 0$, see sequence $\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{7}, ...$.  $\inf C = \frac{1}{3}$. Isn't it?

Comment: Why is $\sup D=\infty$? I suppose $0$ is not a natural number, right? Then, the set should be bounded by $9$.

Comment: in the set $D$ we have $\frac{1}{9}\le \frac{n}{m}\le \frac{9}{1}$, because there are bounds for $n,m$.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I didn't know. Why is $0$ not a natural number?

Comment: @Oleg567 I thought $0 + 10 \le 10$.

Comment: It depends on the Definition, for me $0$ is natural. :) Some authors include $0$ in the naturals, some don't. Both ways have advantages and disadvantages. However, the quotient in the set $D$ is not well defined for $m=0$, thats why I was asking.

Comment: @blue, all depends on $\mathbb{N}$ definition. I used $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, 3, ...\}$. But it can be $\{0,1,2,3,... \}$ also, as I see from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number.

Answer (score 1):

To approach such problems I would suggest first to let one index (or both) run to infinity and take a look at the limit, should it exist.

As for set $B$,
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{n}{m+n} ~=~ 0 ~~\forall n
\quad\text{and}\quad
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{m+n} ~=~ 1 ~~\forall m
$$
Since $m,n$ are are positive, so is $\frac{n}{m+n}$. The fact that you find a sequence of points that converges to $0$ (fix, for instance, $n=1$ and consider the sequence $\{a_m=\frac{1}{1+m}\}_{m\in\mathbb N}\subset B$, by definition you have that *you approach as much as you want* to $0$, and you can indeed conclude that $\inf B =0$.

From the second limit you should observe that, since $n\leq m+n$, then $\frac{n}{m+n}\leq 1$, and apply a similar reasoning to deduce that $\sup B=1$.

I'll leave you the computations for set $C$, which are even easier. As @Oleg567 points out regarding $\inf C$, it would be helpful to observe that the sequence increases wrt variable $n$, so that it achieves its infimum (minimum, then) for the least value of $n$, i.e. $n=1$.

As @Quickbeam2k1 commented, the constraint $m+n\leq 10$ makes set $D$ finite, so no limits should be evaluated. It's pretty much a matter of listing all the values, or, better, to use the fact that $\frac nm$ increases wrt $n$ and decreases wrt $m$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall the following version of  Archimedean Property of $\mathbb{R}$:

> $$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists n\in \mathbb{N}:\frac1n<\epsilon$$